# Why the weighted fractional Sobolev semi-norm si not defined for $p=1$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I already ask the question on MSE ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2638343/why-the-weighted-fractional-sobolev-semi-norm-si-not-defined-for-p-1)), but I didn't had any answer, so I try here.

We defined the Weighted Sobolev semi-norm by $$[u]_{W^{s,p,\alpha }(\Omega )}^p=\iint_{\Omega \times \Omega }\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p |x|^{\alpha _1p}|y|^{\alpha _2p}}{|x-y|^{sp+d}}dxdy,$$
where $\alpha =\alpha _1+\alpha _2$, where $p\in(1,\infty )$. The thing I don't understand is why the case $p=1$ is not allowed ?

You can see reference [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.04918.pdf) or [here](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022123617302732/1-s2.0-S0022123617302732-main.pdf?_tid=6c9c31d2-0b21-11e8-83cf-00000aacb361&acdnat=1517910062_ab8df5b2e08a939003987cbdb4827883) or [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.04724.pdf). I really don't understand why $p=1$ can't be considered.

Comment: I don't think the issue is that they cannot define the seminorm; I think the issue is that the results/method of proof in the papers only applies to give good inequalities when $p >1$. (Where did you see in the papers that say the seminorm cannot be defined when $p = 1$? For the unweighted case certainly the classical Slobodeckij seminorm allows $p = 1$.)

Comment: @WillieWong : Thank you for your answer. The writer of the second paper (H.-M. Nguyen) told me that the double integral may not converge when $p=1$. But to me it also may not converge when $p\neq 1$, no ?